# S.O.S my Upright Piano keys aren'r working

Tags: piano, chords, key

please someone help me! I have an ED.SEILER upright wood piano with ivory keys, that's from 1911 (so it's 106 years old) and some of the black keys stopped working! It was working perfectly like a week ago! I'm in major panic! What do I do???

Comment: Call a technician.

Comment: @Tetsujin said the main the thing. But if you manage to open the piano lid, check to see if some of the hammers are out of place. If they are, gently tap them to help them get back into place. Some times in old pianos the return mechanism gets stuck and the hammers rest out of place, it may or may not be your case. If the hammers don't respond to a gentle tap, DON'T FORCE them (yeah, call the technician) .

Answer (score 1):

Did you do anything between the black keys working and them not working?  Like moving the piano, or taking the front off to 'have a look' and maybe also have a fiddle?  Or might someone else have?  This can happen when the action has been taken out and not replaced properly.

Anyway, you won't do any great harm by removing the front panel and having a look.  Is everything in place?  Has anything fallen into the piano?  Are some notes 'stuck'?   But if there isn't an obvious simple solution, call a piano tuner/technician.  Don't risk further damage by poking around beyond your capabilities.